# flare-vm installation not completed?

Tags: windows

*** I'm not really sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of question. If not, let me know the right site. Thanks

I've just installed flare-vm via `install.ps1` script from 
https://github.com/fireeye/flare-vm as shown below.

[image]

According to https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2018/11/flare-vm-update.html

> After completing the installation, you will be presented with the
>   following desktop environment:

[image]

It took more than hour to install it, however I notice that it didn't really looks like the screenshot on it's website.

As example, the wallpaper didn't change and I still have the default Windows wallpaper.

My question how to verify if the installation was completed without any error, and there was no missing package?

Comment: https://github.com/fireeye/flare-vm/issues

Comment: do you have all the tools installed?